# Multiple ExecStartPre in sequence issues in a systemd service

Tags: linux, systemd, process, services

In my `systemd` service file below, I wish to execute some things in a strict order using multiple `ExecStartPre` as shown below.

`/app/prescript` should first run to completion, then `/app/revertscript.sh` should run to completion after that. This should all happen before `ExecStart`.

However, the `ExecStartPre` scripts are not running to completion, especially `/app/revertscript.sh`

Is what I'm doing correct for what I wish to achieve?

```
[Unit]
Description=app2 
ConditionPathExists=/app
After=network.target uncrypte_app.service uncrypte_data.service

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/app
ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /var/run/appd.pid
ExecStartPre=/app/prescript
ExecStartPre=/app/revertscript.sh
ExecStart=/app/appd start
ExecStop=/app/appd stop
RemainAfterExit=yes
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: In my opinion, I would group the commands you want executed in sequence into a single shell script.